# d3.js can not update the chart - using json data

Tags: d3.js

I've been trying to get the update chart function to work... what am I doing wrong?

I've created a function to build the chart.

Then an update function once input boxes are changed - so if a user changes the data and then hits update.

I am unable to try and access the existing pie chart and update it/animate it with the correct data.

```
$.Core.doughnutCommon ={
    init: function(){
        var that = this;

        var colourtheme = {
            "spectrum" :  ["#e87424", "#ebb700", "#007c92"]
        };

        $('[data-doughnut-pie-common="true"]').each(function(index) {
            that.bindInputEvents($(this));
            var holder = $(this)[0];
            var data = that.generateData(holder);

            console.log("data", data);      
            var theme = $(this).data("theme");
            var colours = colourtheme[theme];
            var radius = 64;    
            that.buildchart(holder, index, data, colours, radius);          
        });
    },
    bindInputEvents: function(holder){
        var that = this;
        holder.find('.updatechart').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            that.updatechart(holder);
        });

        holder.find('.dataset li input').keyup(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.value').text($(this).val());
        });         
    },
    generateData: function(holder){
        var that = this;

        var json = new Array();

        var keysObj = {};
        var legendsarray = new Array();

                $(holder).find('.dataset li').each(function(index) {

                      var key = $(this).find('.key').text();
                      var value = $(this).find('.value').text();

                        //__key obj
                        var localKeyObj = {};
                        localKeyObj[key] = "";                

                        //__legend array build
                        var stream = {
                            "name" : key,
                            "population" : value
                        }

                      jQuery.extend(keysObj, localKeyObj);

                      legendsarray.push(stream);      
                });     

                var obj ={
                    "legends": legendsarray
                };

                jQuery.extend(obj, keysObj);

                json.push(obj);     
                return json;
    },
    updatechart: function(holder){
        var that = this;

        console.log("holder", holder);

        var data = that.generateData(holder);
        console.log("data hold", data);

        var pieId = holder.find(".pie").attr("id");


        //draw arc paths
        //var svg = d3.select('#'+pieId);

        var arc_group = d3.select('#'+pieId+' .sliceholder');



        var color = d3.scale.ordinal();

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(64)
            .innerRadius(64 - 20);      

        paths = arc_group.selectAll("path").data(data[0].legends);


        paths.enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "arc")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) { 

                console.log("d", d);
                return color(d.name); 

            })
            .transition()
            .duration(500);
            //.attrTween("d", arcTween);

        paths
            .transition()
            .duration(500);
            //.attrTween("d", arcTween);

        paths.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            //.attrTween("d", arcTween);
            .remove();




        function arcTween(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
        }


    },
    buildchart: function(holder, index, data, colours, radius){
        var padding = 10;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(colours);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(radius - 20);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) { return d.population; });


        color.domain(
            d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
                return key !== "legends"; 
            })
        );      

        var svg = d3.select(holder).selectAll(".pie")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("svg")
            .attr("class", "pie")
            .attr("id", "pie"+index)
            .attr("width", radius * 2)
            .attr("height", radius * 2)
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "sliceholder")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

        svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(function(d) { return pie(d.legends); })
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "arc")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });

        var legend = d3.select(holder).append("svg")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", radius * 1.7)
            .attr("height", radius * 2)
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 25 + ")"; });

        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", color);

        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d; });   

        var totalUnits = svg.append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "units")
            .attr("dy", 5)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // text-align: right
            .text("Chart title");
    }
};
```

The html is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.Core ={
                init: function(){
                    console.log("test");
                    $.Core.doughnutCommon.init();//iniate doughnut read only
                }
            };
</script>           
<script type="text/javascript" src="doughnut.common.js"></script>   

<script>            
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.Core.init();
    });
</script>

<div class="doughnut_pie common" data-doughnut-pie-common="true" data-theme="spectrum">
    <form>
        <ul class="dataset">
            <li>
                <span class="key">Equities</span>
                <span class="value">50</span>
                <span class="varbox"><input type="text" value="50"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="key">Bonds</span>
                <span class="value">30</span>
                <span class="varbox"><input type="text" value="30"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="key">Gilts</span>
                <span class="value">20</span>
                <span class="varbox"><input type="text" value="20"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button class="updatechart">UPDATE</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code and almost no explanation. What doesn't work, i.e. what do you expect to happen and what does actually happen? Which part of the code are you struggling with?

Comment: The chart renders initially with data. But when trying to edit the data aka provide it with a new set of data - and invoke the update function - its not updating the pie slices.. it doesn't animate.

Comment: Does it not update at all or just not animate?

Comment: It doesn't update or animate. It looks to me sometimes its trying to create paths... but I just don't know whats wrong.

Comment: Here is the latest working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/cCusn/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First, the selector

```
var arc_group = d3.select('#'+pieId+' .sliceholder');
```

doesn't work because the `g` element with class `sliceholder` is a subelement of the SVG. You need

```
var arc_group = d3.select('#'+pieId+' > .sliceholder');
```

Second, you can't pass in the raw data when updating, you need to process it with a pie layout first. That is,

```
paths = arc_group.selectAll("path").data(data[0].legends);
```

won't work, you need

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.population; });
    paths = arc_group.selectAll("path").data(pie(data[0].legends));
```

Third, you've missed some initialisation when copying the `arcTween` code. You need to set the initial values for `._current`:

```
svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(function(d) { return pie(d.legends); })
        .enter().append("path")
        ...
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });
```

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cCusn/3/).

Comment: Thank you very much Lars. I've been struggling with it for hours. So I need to access the g class using >